# VUE: Issues with fetching data when I use Pagination

Tags: vue.js, pagination, axios, token, laravel-5.6

I have a a set of data which I can access for the first page. But as soon as I use the pagination and trying to press next page, then I can't access the data. I get the 401 issue.

```
created(){
          this.fetchNotater();
        },
        methods: {
            fetchNotater(page_url){
                let vm = this;

// api/borgernotater works perfectly. But when I use the page_url then it won't accept my api_token

                page_url = page_url || 'api/borgernotater'; 
                fetch(`${page_url}?api_token=${window.Laravel.apiToken}`)
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(res => {
                        this.notater = res.data;
                        vm.makePagination(res);
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err))
            },
            makePagination(res){
                let pagination = {
                    current_page: res.current_page,
                    last_page: res.last_page,
                    next_page_url: res.next_page_url,
                    prev_page_url: res.prev_page_url
                };
                this.pagination = pagination;
            }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like an issue with your API token. 401 error indicates that you are attempting to access an unauthorized resource.

Comment: I can fetch data, so the API token works fine on the first page. But when I use the pagination, then it wont accept it and I get the 401 error.

Comment: As I said, it seems to be an authorization problem.

Comment: But why do I get the autorization issue for the borgernotat?page=2?api_token=xxxxxx but not in borgernotat?api_token=xxxxxx ? Could you give me any hints how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your API request URL construction: parameters need to be separated with `&`. You can see that when you are requesting page 2, you have two questions marks in your URL and that’s an invalid query string, and the API request URL will not be parsed correctly. It should be: `?page=2&api_key=...`.

With that in mind, it might be helpful to use a third party library, like query-string on NPM, to perform parsing and adding payload to your query string.